# How to get shape of tensor from TFRecordDataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have following feature written to my training TFRecord:

```
feature = {'label': _int64_feature(gt),
           'image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(im.tostring())),
           'height': _int64_feature(h),
           'width': _int64_feature(w)}
```

and I am reading it like:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_file)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_func)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
```

whereas my parse_func looks like this:

```
def parse_func(ex):
    feature = {'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'label': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
               'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
    features = tf.parse_single_example(ex, features=feature)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.uint8)
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
    im_shape = tf.stack([width, height])
    image = tf.reshape(image, im_shape)
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    return image, label
```

Now, I want to get the shape of **image** and **label** like:

```
image.get_shape().as_list()
```

which prints

[None, None, None]

instead of 

[None, 224, 224] (size of the image (batch, width, height))

Is there any function which can give me the size of these tensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your map function "parse_func" is part of the graph as an operation and it doesn't know the fixed size of your input and labels a priori, using get_shape() wouldn't return the expected fixed shape.

If your image, label shape is fixed, as a hack, you can try reshaping your image, labels with the already known size(this would in effect wouldn't do anything at all, but will explicitly set the size of the output tensors).

ex.
image = tf.reshape(image, [224,224])

With this you should be able to get the get_shape() result as expected.

Comment: Hard coding does solve the problem for now, but I am looking for more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is storing the encoded images instead of decoded raw bytes, that way you only need to decode the image back using tensorflow when reading the tfrecords, which will also help you saving storage, and this way you will be able to get the image shape out from the tensors.

```py
    # Load your image as you would normally do then do:

    # Convert the image to raw bytes.
    img_bytes = tf.io.encode_jpeg(img).numpy()

    # Create a dict with the data we want to save in the
    # TFRecords file. You can add more relevant data here.
    data = \
    {'image': wrap_bytes(img_bytes),
     'label': wrap_int64(label)}

    # Wrap the data as TensorFlow Features.
    feature = tf.train.Features(feature=data)

    # Wrap again as a TensorFlow Example.
    example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)

    # Serialize the data.
    serialized = example.SerializeToString()
            
    # Write the serialized data to the TFRecords file.
    writer.write(serialized)
```

#### And then for reading you can use:

```py
    features = \
        {
            'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)            
        }

    # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
    parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized,
                                             features=features)

    # Get the image as raw bytes.
    image_raw = parsed_example['image']

    # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image_raw)
    
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) # optional
    
    # Get the label associated with the image.
    label = parsed_example['label']
    
    # The image and label are now correct TensorFlow types.
    return image, label
```